# Senders Notifications

Tags: docusignapi

I have the following json request, if I do not use any senders notifications, it works but if I add the senders notifications it does not, why?

```
{
"userSettings":[
{
     "value":"false",
     "name":"allowSendOnBehalfOf"
}
],
"signerEmailNotifications":{
    "envelopeActivation":"false",
    "envelopeComplete":"false",
    "carbonCopyNotification":"false",
    "certifiedDeliveryNotification":"false",
    "envelopeDeclined":"false",
    "envelopeVoided":"false",
    "envelopeCorrected":"false",
    "reassignedSigner":"false",
    "purgeDocuments":"false",
    "faxReceived":"false",
    "documentMarkupActivation":"false",
    "agentNotification":"false"
},
"senderEmailNotifications":{
    "envelopeComplete":"false",
    "changedSigner":"false",
    "senderEnvelopeDeclined":"false",
    "withdrawnConsent":"false",
    "recipientViewed":"false",
    "deliveryFailed":"false"
 }
}"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove the final `"` from your request, it works for me.

```
{
"userSettings":[
{
     "value":"false",
     "name":"allowSendOnBehalfOf"
}
],
"signerEmailNotifications":{
    "envelopeActivation":"false",
    "envelopeComplete":"false",
    "carbonCopyNotification":"false",
    "certifiedDeliveryNotification":"false",
    "envelopeDeclined":"false",
    "envelopeVoided":"false",
    "envelopeCorrected":"false",
    "reassignedSigner":"false",
    "purgeDocuments":"false",
    "faxReceived":"false",
    "documentMarkupActivation":"false",
    "agentNotification":"false"
},
"senderEmailNotifications":{
    "envelopeComplete":"false",
    "changedSigner":"false",
    "senderEnvelopeDeclined":"false",
    "withdrawnConsent":"false",
    "recipientViewed":"false",
    "deliveryFailed":"false"
 }
}
```

Leaving the " in there you get an error message, indicating that your request has additional text after the JSON is closed

```
{
 errorCode: "INVALID_REQUEST_BODY"
 message: "The request body is missing or improperly formatted. Additional text encountered after finished reading JSON content: \". Path '', line 30, position 2."
}
```

Comment: In my original call i do not have the quotation marks, I made a mistake here.

Comment: What error message are you getting? It's hard to debug what's going on with only a piece of the information

Comment: I get The remote server returned an error: (400) Bad Request.

Comment: How did you manage to get the specific error code, all I get is a The remote server returned an error: (400) Bad Request.

Comment: What is the URL you're calling?